# Auto SSO Authentication for Windows Users over Angular WebApp

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have been working on an angular application using angular 1.5. I am setting up an automatic single sign-on using the window's username for authentication but don't know where to start. What should one look for dealing with the scenario?

Comment: It depends on which authentication method you want to use, OAauth2.0, SAML etc.